# No instance for (Show a0) arising from a use of `print' in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I am new in Haskell. The topic is from Learn you Haskell book "recursive data structures"

Here is my code

```
data List a = Empty | Cons a (List a) deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord) 

main = do
    print $ Empty
    print $ 5 `Cons` Empty 
    print $ 4 (Cons 5 Empty)  
    print $ 3 `Cons` (4 `Cons` (5 `Cons` Empty))
```

and here is the error message I get

```
No instance for (Show a0) arising from a use of `print'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Show a => Show (List a)
```

Comment: Isn't the third `print` causing problems? Here you provide a `4` and a `Cons 5 Empy`, so you apply `(Cons 5 Empty)` on `4`?

Comment: I get a different error message when trying to run your code as posted here. That's because there is a typo: in the third line of the do-block, you meant to write ``print $ 4 `Cons` (5 `Cons` Empty)``.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Empty` can be any type of `List`, and although it happens to be the case that `show Empty` will be `"Empty"` in all cases where `show` works at all, the compiler doesn't really know that. (For a real-life example where things could differ by type, compare `show ([] :: [Int])` and `show ([] :: [Char])` in ghci.) So it demands that you pick a type to use to help it decide how to run `show Empty`. Pretty easy fix:

```
main = do
    print $ (Empty :: List Int)
    ...
```

Don't forget to add a `Cons` to the `4 (Cons 5 Empty)` line, too!